# How can I create a playfab leaderboard for a local 2 player game using login details?

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, statistics, leaderboard, playfab

I want to get the 2 players playing my pool game to login separately and play the main game. Is there a way I can use login details to store stats in leaderboard formats in playfab?

I have set up playfab and have got a functioning login page in unity using the playfab api. The page can register new users, allow log in and send account recovery emails.